# Suppose we wish to interpolate n + 1 data points (n > 2) with a piecewise quadratic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we wish to interpolate n + 1 data points (n > 2) with a piecewise quadratic polynomial. How many continous derivatives at most can this interpolant be guaranteed to have without becoming one global polynomial? Explain.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I understand that the piecewise quadratic polynomial is v(x) = si(x) = ai + bi(x-ti) + ci(x-ti)^2, ti <= x <= ti+1 , i = 0,..., r-1. But I didn't understand about the global polynomial. This question is from the book A First Course in Numerical Methods, chapter 11 question 2.

Comment: Did you read about [spline interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#:~:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,piecewise%20polynomial%20called%20a%20spline.)?